# ruby string method

Tags: ruby

In my program I want to add a method for double letters in a string. My question is there a public method to that? For example:

> `'The'` → `TThhee'`

Here's what I have:

```
puts "Please enter text: "
input = gets
letters = input.chomp.to_s
puts "You entered: " + letters + "."

list_letters = letters.split(//)
list = list_letters.join(". ")* 2.to_i  

puts "Your text is made up of the letters: " + list + "."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
letters.gsub(/(.)/, '\1\1')
```

or even shorter:

```
letters.gsub(/./, '\&\&')
```

A bit more comfortable:

```
class String
  def char_duplicate
    self.gsub(/./, '\&\&')
  end
end

puts "abc".char_duplicate #aabbcc
puts "abca".char_duplicate #aabbccaa
```

---

Your example code makes something different. Perhaps you wanted to do something like:

```
 letters.split(//).map{|x| x * 2 }.join
```

or

```
 letters.each_char.map{|x| x * 2 }.join
```

Comment: `gsub(/./, '\&\&')` eliminates the need for a match group.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Thanks, I adopted my answer

Answer (score 3):

Just to be different:

```
(['The'.each_char.to_a]*2).transpose.join
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in a single line, even if somewhat contrived. I've gone for inject because I thought not duplicating spaces would be nice.

```
>> "foo bar".chomp.split("").inject([]) { |a,l| l =~ /\S/ ? a << l*2 : a << l }.join("")
=> "ffoooo bbaarr"
```

EDIT: On second thought, you can also just

```
>> "foo bar".gsub(/\S/, '\&\&')
=> "ffoooo bbaarr"
```

Goes to show how little Ruby I've done lately =)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as @knut did. For fun variety, however, here are some more:

```
irb(main):002:0> s.chars.map{ |c| c*2 }.join
#=> "TThhee"

irb(main):004:0> s.chars.zip(s.chars).join
#=> "TThhee"

irb(main):005:0> s.chars.inject(""){ |d,c| d << c << c }
#=> "TThhee"

irb(main):010:0> "".tap{ |d| s.each_char{ |c| d << c*2 } }
#=> "TThhee"
```